# When I try to run `git push heroku master` it is giving an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, buildpack

I am trying to develop a university web app using ruby on rails for my college project .
I am using ruby version - 5.1.7 and rails version 2.6.3
This is github link for project code reference -

https://github.com/NSWEETY/online_management

When I try to run `git push heroku master` it is giving an error:

```
(base) sweety@sweety-INVALID:~/Downloads/online_management$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 330, done.
Counting objects: 100% (330/330), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (180/180), done.
Writing objects: 100% (330/330), 2.74 MiB | 360.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 330 (delta 120), reused 330 (delta 120)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:             HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to powerful-gorge-42453.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/powerful-gorge-42453.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/powerful-gorge-42453.git'
```

Comment: You're not providing us with anything related to the code/project you're having the problem with. Dumping an error message and hoping for a hail mary isn't a good practice. On the other hand, have you tried following the hint in the error message? Right below the `No default language could be detected for this app.`, which I imagine you did not specify either?

Comment: I have provided the information regarding the project